# Image upload goes to "None" folder in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, image-uploading, django-1.11

I'm trying to upload an image via ajax. The image uploads well, but it is delivered inside a "None" folder, between the `MEDIA_ROOT` value and `upload_to` parameter of `ImageField`.

My current settings are as follows:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media'))
```

Inside my app's models.py:

```
image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=get_image_path)
```

and

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(connection.tenant.schema_name, 'img', 'devices', filename)
```

When I upload the image, it goes to `static/media/None/(tenant.schema_name)/img/devices`, instead of `static/media/(tenant.schema_name)/img/devices`

(In the picture, `tenant.schema_name` is "ars")

[image: wrong path image upload]

The form is as follows:

```
class DeviceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['name', 'model', 'serial', 'location', 'note', 'image', 'page', 'address']
```

And the saving snippet:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.POST.dict()
        form = DeviceForm(post_data, request.FILES)
        if not form.is_valid():
            return JsonResponse({"message": "Form is invalid"}, status=400)
        obj = form.save()
        return JsonResponse(obj.to_dict(), safe=False)
```

Is there a configuration that I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT:** Here's the whole `settings.py`:

```
import os
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = (key)

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

if DEBUG:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']   # Allow any host during debug mode
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

SHARED_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'cloud_admin',
    'cloud_core',

]

TENANT_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'cloud_core.users',
    'cloud_data',
    'cloud_apps.dashboard',
    'cloud_apps.device',
    'cloud_apps.device_pages.kr',
    # 'cloud_apps',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]

MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'ArsCloud.middleware.TenantSelectionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'ArsCloud.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ArsCloud.urls_public'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cloud_core", "templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cloud_admin", "templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cloud_data", "templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cloud_apps", "dashboard", "templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cloud_apps", "device", "templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cloud_apps", "device-pages", "templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cloud_apps", "device-pages", "kr", "templates"),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'cloud_core.context_processors.tenant'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ArsCloud.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    (database)
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
    'tenant_schemas.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Language support
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/')
]
LANGUAGES = (
    (u'ja', ugettext_lazy('Japanese')),
    (u'en', ugettext_lazy('English'))
)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
# ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
    )

MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media'))
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'


LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = [
    "upload_device_data"
]

TENANT_MODEL = 'cloud_core.Tenant'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'tenant_schemas.storage.TenantFileSystemStorage'
PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'ArsCloud.urls_public'
ADMIN_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'ArsCloud.urls_admin'
TENANT_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'ArsCloud.urls_tenant'
ARSUSER_SCHEMA = "ars"

POST_TOKEN_KEY = {'key': (key), 'iv': "Salt for hashing"}


DUMMY_DB_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'falsedb')
DUMMY_DB_FILE = os.path.join(DUMMY_DB_PATH, 'config.json')
```

I used the config suggested by the answer below, but I still have a "None" folder between `MEDIA_ROOT` and the `upload_to` parameter

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#media-root) state that this must be an "absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files" - you have provided a relative path. Try changing it to an absolute path?

Comment: @solarissmoke Still nothing. Tried full path from `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`, but still the same "None" folder

Comment: What have you defined for `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: @solarissmoke As for now, it's not declared. It's still in development so docs said that there's no need to define it now. And as I inherited this project and don't know much about django, I tried to set it and it broke the css and js calls

Comment: You have conflicting statements. In your question you expect the images to go under `static` yet you define your media folder as `static/media`. Please clarify and edit your question to reflect your latest setup.

Comment: Please post your ajax call.

Comment: @DanSwain I think the ajax call should be irrelevant, since all data is saved correctly, and despite wrong path, the image is saved successfully. So probably it has to do with django configuration

Comment: I am not sure if this is your problem but when you should generally use the _callable method_ to make `upload_to` use the return value of a function. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to and specifically the part that starts with _"upload_to may also be a callable, such as a function."_.

Answer (score 1):

You should define media dir in settings.py file. images and files that you want to upload from website, store in media dir.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
    )

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

you need static directory inside of your project. Tree directory is like this:

```
static -
        |-static_root
        |-static_dirs
        |-media
```

please create these 4 directories: **static**, **static_root**, **static_dirs**, **media**

Comment: Sorry for the lateness. I did it and I got a 404 on all my assets. So I moved them under `static_dirs`. But now I have the same error

Answer (score -1):

Create media and static as folders both at the same level in your overall project directory (the same level as manage.py) and then try:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The media and static folders are used for two completely different things and media should never be nested inside static.  The media folder is for user-uploaded content, and the `MEDIA_ROOT` you define is where user-uploaded content is uploaded to (with sub-folders within MEDIA_ROOT being set via `upload_to=.....`).  The static folder and (and sub-folders) hold content that you define as part of the website (e.g. css, js).

I would also make this small change (no need for `request.POST.dict()`):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DeviceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Sorry, I went into an editing storm. In my current setting, `connection.tenant.schema_name` is evaluated as "ars", as shown in the new picture

Comment: I thought this at first, but then where is `ars` coming from?

Comment: @Selcuk from the db, each user belongs to a tenant. In this case, the tenant name is "ars"

Comment: @RobertoMaldonado Yes, I was replying to DanSwain. Sorry for the confusion.